# Fatal error in Yii immediately after adding eager-loading

Tags: php, yii, eager-loading

I've got 3 `CActiveRecord` models:

- A
- B
- C

Relationships:

- A has many B.
- A has many C.
- B belongs to A.
- C belongs to A.

In `AController`'s `actionHome($id)`, I'm retrieving the single row of `A` from the database. Just like the default `actionView($id)`.

In my View for `actionHome()`, I also list all instances of `B` and `C` that belong to that `A`.

```
public function actionHome($id)
{
  $this->render('home', array('a' => A::model()->findByPk($id)));
}
```

In `actionHome()`, I want to use **eager loading** of `A`'s relationships.

But, when I add `with()` to the `findByPk()` function, I immediately get a fatal error.

```
public function actionHome($id)
{
  $this->render('home', array('a' => A::model()->with('bs','cs')->findByPk($id)));
}
```

`Fatal error: Call to a member function label() on a non-object in` my `home.php` view file.

`label()` is a public static function I have within my `A` model class.

So, since I've added eager loading, this causes the function to be unavailable.

Can someone please assist?
Why would this function no longer be available?

`label()` is called in my view home.php like so:

```
$this->breadcrumbs = array(
  CHtml::encode($a->label(2)) => array('index'),
  CHtml::encode($a->name),
);
```

`label()` is defined as follows in my model:

```
public static function label($n = 1) 
{
  if ( $n == 0 ) $n = 1;
  return Yii::t('app', 'A|As', $n);
}
```

If I comment-out the call to `label()` within the view (or change the call to `A::label(2)`), then the next line just triggers an error too,.. that "name" is not a property of non-object.

Obviously, for some reason, `$a` is no longer an object.

**Update 1:**

Adding `with()` causes `findByPk($id)` to return `NULL`, therefore `$a` is `NULL` in my view, so I'm trying to find why. Lazy loading doesn't have this issue.

Comment: Could default scopes on my models have something to do with returning a NULL? I'm not sure why it'd be different between lazy-loading and eager-loading though.

Comment: why don't you turn on logging and see what queries are being executed, that way it'll become easier to debug

Comment: Why do you use `with` with `findByPk`? `with` is useful only if there is a condition in a related table, but `findBYPk` only searches for a primary key, on one table.

Comment: Your model A is definitively empty.

Comment: @Örs Maybe I don't understand `with` properly. The view I'm working on currently has 70 queries being executed. The user goes to http://example.com/a/home/1 to see all their instances of `B` and `C` that belong to their `A`. I think the whole View should be able to load with a MAX of 7 queries no matter how many instances of `B` and `C` the user has for their 'A'. I think my `foreach` loop in the View triggers an extra 3 queries for every iteration of `B` or `C`. I was hoping `with` would just load it all up front.

Comment: By the way, you are calling a `static` method in a non-static manner; that's an `E_STRICT` error. Should be changed to `A::label(2)`. Not related to the question, just good practice.

Answer (score 1):

The `findByPk()` is returning `NULL` because the relation `cs` is empty. Yii is doing an `INNER JOIN` from `A` to `B` and because there are no `B`'s that belong to `A`, the resultset is empty.

Lazy-loading didn't have this problem because it doesn't do the query until data from `B` is needed.

Comment: That said, even using `with()`, the view is still executing 70 queries. I must not understand the use of `with()` or how to do eager-loading properly. I feel like just doing a manual SQL query.

Comment: You should read the documentation before you do anything else.